# Get points from polygons with extreme angles

Tags: postgis

I intend to remove points from a polygons with extreme angles like the image link

1. Get the points
2. Remove from linestring

[image: error points]

I make my buffer like this...

```
SELECT (ST_Dump(
          ST_Union(
             ST_BUFFER(the_geom, 10, 'endcap=flat join=round')))).geom as the_geom 
FROM mytable
```

The error is on buffer unions, see the image.

I want to remove that points.

Comment: http://s32.postimg.org/mp6bxcyit/linestring.png

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck, what language/platform are you using? Is there some code to evaluate? We need to know where you're up to to tell you where to go next. You say PostGIS, but is that SQL or are you accessing the objects via OGR or QGIS etc..

Comment: Please include images locally.  Remote links fail over time, making the question useless.  Use the **edit** button to update questions with details requested in comments.

Comment: I was going to upload the image for you, but it timed out, nicely illustrating Vince's point.

Comment: how long those slivers are ? if they are small you can remove them by using st_buffer(st_buffer(geom, 1),-1) . another option is use St_generalize or write script using st_dump , calculate length and angle between points, and then remove unneeded points and re-create line

Comment: Related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/173977

Comment: These are sometimes known as "cutbacks," btw. And they're not a reliable way of identifying these anomalies.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks simplexio, I used your idea: `st_buffer(st_buffer(geom, 1),-1)`

Buffer 10m: `st_buffer(st_buffer(geom, 10-1),1)`