# Deleting small gaps (slivers) between polygons?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, delete, slivers

I try to delete the slivers that appeared when I have merged some polygons.

I have two different cases:[image]

For the **CASE 1**, no problem I fill the gap with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sliver_killer(geometry,float) RETURNS geometry AS
$$ SELECT ST_BuildArea(ST_Collect(a.geom)) as final_geom
FROM ST_DumpRings($1) AS a
WHERE a.path[1] = 0 OR
(a.path[1] > 0 AND ST_Area(a.geom) > $2)
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;

UPDATE merged SET geom = sliver_killer(geom,50::float);
```

A function that fill all the gaps smaller than x square meter.

**BUT** for the **CASE 2**, when the small gaps are "open" I can't manage to fill those gaps.

I have try something like: buffer(1) followed by buffer(-1)  but of course I obtain some rounded corners. Did someone have a true solution ?

Comment: did you try buffer(0) ?

Comment: ST_MakeValid could also work ...

Comment: @WKT the problem is that the sliver is just bigger than the tolerance and the geometry is perfecly valid (no self intersection, nothing like that)

Comment: ST_ConcaveHull ?

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173977/how-to-remove-spikes-in-polygons-with-postgis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I found an answer:

You can avoid to get rounded corner by adding the parameter `'join=mitre'` to st_buffer:

So it work perfectly fine with:

```
SELECT st_buffer(st_buffer(geom,1,'join=mitre'),-1,'join=mitre') FROM mygeotable;
```

**EDIT**

If the buffer is too large st_buffer(geom,10,'join=mitre') produce from time to time some strange results (the polygones become spiky). So to avoid this effect it's safer to preserve the old boundary with st_intersection:

```
SELECT st_intersection(st_buffer(st_buffer(geom,-1,'join=mitre'),1,'join=mitre'),geom) FROM mygeotable;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ST_Buffer` solution already explained here is valid, but it can be improved in order to avoid the spikes (and the intersection step itself). You need to add a new parameter to the buffer `mitre_limit`.

```
SELECT st_intersection(
          st_buffer(
             st_buffer(geom, 1, 'join=mitre mitre_limit=1.0'
          ), -1, 'join=mitre mitre_limit=1.0'
        ), geom) as
FROM _mygeotable_ ;
```

This way you will get what you want much easier and cleaner.

Comment: Hi, where can I find some explanation in the docu about what mitre and mitre_limit do?