# PostGIS function ST_Union leaving extra lines and artifacts

Tags: postgis

I am trying to dissolve polygons based on a column type using PostGIS 10.4.  I am pre-compiling tables, so time requirements are not really an issue.  ST_Union does almost everything that I want straight out of the box.  However, the ST_Union is has left lots of artifact lines inside the polygon as seen in the pictures below.  Is anyone aware of a way to remove the lines *inside* the polygons?  I am not sure if there is a better way to make the union call or rather to clean the polygons up after the union.

`INSERT into new_table (count_field, geom)
SELECT count_comp, ST_Union(geom) as geom
FROM old_table
GROUP BY count_field;`

[image]

Comment: I'd say that's most likely due to small gaps between those polygons, i.e. a topology issue.

Comment: if this indeed are tiny gaps and holes, it's a little tricky to get them out while preserving those inner rings you want. you could first check your dissolved polygons with `ST_NumInteriorRings` and see if they have plenty. you can get the outer ring as linestring with `ST_ExteriorRing` or a set of all rings with `ST_DumpRings` (use `ST_MakePolygon` with either to get back polygons). this get's more complicated if any of those rings are invalid. see [this](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/postgis_tips_tricks/92/filtering-rings-in-polygon-postgis) excellent blog on the topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting small gaps (slivers) between polygons?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198115/deleting-small-gaps-slivers-between-polygons)

Comment: I have seen this a lot and it can be solved by doing a small positive buffer, ST_Buffer(geom, x) before ST_Union and then reverse this after with ST_Buffer(geom, -x). You could also try using ST_SnapToGrid on the input polygons. It is likely to be cause by minor precision issues or small gaps as @ThingumaBob pointed out.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça +1 for simplicity ,)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After following advice from tThingumaBob and JohnPowellakaBarça, I was able to remove the slivers. `ST_NumInteriorRings`, `ST_ExteriorRing`, `ST_DumpRings` didn't work for me, but ST_Buffer() did.
Just for reference, if anyone else is working at the parcel level scale, the x value that ended up working for me was `0.00001`.  So my final query was
`INSERT into new_table (count_field, geom)
SELECT count_field, ST_Buffer(ST_Union(ST_Buffer(geom, 0.00001)), -0.00001) as geom
FROM old_table
GROUP BY count_field;`

Thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to st_snap polygon to each other with [ST_Snap](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange!  Please take a moment to take the tour to learn about our focused Q&A format. For answers, we are looking for more than just a short sentence/question -- please edit your answer to elaborate on why you think this will work. As you gain reputation you will be able to comment on questions, which can be used to ask for clarification.