# Reproject valid features returns geomety error with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry-conversion, self-intersection

PostGIS3.2, PostgreSQL 13

---

I have a table with multipolygons.

There is a constraint `CHECK (st_isvalid(geom))` on it.

Run a query with `st_ivalid(geom)` returns no error fortunately !

When I try to transform geometries from `EPSG:2154` to `EPSG:4326` in an other column with the **same** constraint, PostGIS says `Self-intersection at or near point...`

The (first?) problem is that, for example, this original feature is obviously weird :

[image: false polygon]

Here is the WKT : `MULTIPOLYGON(((856968.0809475727 6518031.45147972,856930.3185529013 6518034.334114722,856934.1697799985 6518064.89914313,856944.1786493242 6518064.033092295,856989.9199941442 6518060.081799399,856991.3227799159 6518059.973267407,857054.4690395503 6518054.579191504,857168.1567043017 6518044.903213004,857067.2389138227 6518053.492345106,857072.3044749431 6518022.810888314,857070.9721031557 6518015.4990919195,857068.8029368921 6518002.930926339,857063.1728536686 6517996.683402535,857052.3188981324 6517997.593314975,857052.4488856238 6518016.896457455,857052.5138793695 6518024.273247593,856995.1650229847 6518028.505965281,856995.1325261119 6518029.448374595,856988.3081828107 6518029.935827687,856968.0809475727 6518031.45147972)))`

but like I said above, `select... WHERE st_isvalid() = 'f'` returns nothing.

So if the geometry seems to be valid at the start, it becomes false when I reproject it.

I can't correct thousand of geometries one by one.
As far as I know, `makevalid(geom)` or `buffer(geom, 0)` are useless.

The only solution seems to delete the constraint check validity on the target column EPSG:4326 (not very desired).

Unless anyone has encountered and solved this issue?

Comment: Please copy one problematic geometry as WKT into your question.

Comment: WKT geometry added

Comment: The input geometry is topologically valid but I no not believe that the spike is there intentionally. Maybe you can find some ideas for pre-processing from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173977/how-to-remove-spikes-in-polygons-with-postgis.

Answer (score 2):

It looks valid and I can transform it:

```
with cte as (
            select st_setsrid(st_geometryfromtext('MULTIPOLYGON(((856968.0809475727 6518031.45147972,856930.3185529013 6518034.334114722,856934.1697799985 6518064.89914313,856944.1786493242 6518064.033092295,856989.9199941442 6518060.081799399,856991.3227799159 6518059.973267407,857054.4690395503 6518054.579191504,857168.1567043017 6518044.903213004,857067.2389138227 6518053.492345106,857072.3044749431 6518022.810888314,857070.9721031557 6518015.4990919195,857068.8029368921 6518002.930926339,857063.1728536686 6517996.683402535,857052.3188981324 6517997.593314975,857052.4488856238 6518016.896457455,857052.5138793695 6518024.273247593,856995.1650229847 6518028.505965281,856995.1325261119 6518029.448374595,856988.3081828107 6518029.935827687,856968.0809475727 6518031.45147972)))') ,2154) as geom
            )           

select st_isvalid(geom), st_transform(geom, 4326) as geom from cte
```

If you want to select valid geometries the syntax is:

```
where st_isvalid(geom) is True
```

Comment: But the transformation is not valid: select st_isvalid(st_transform(geom, 4326)) from cte ->false best is to use st_buffer(geom,0) after transforming

Comment: yes you are correct. You can make it valid: `st_isvalid(st_makevalid(geom))` return `True`